# R: Trouble using ifelse to run multiple logical tests across dataframes to create new column

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, match

I'm trying to using the retrosheet baseball game data name the catcher for any given pitch pulled during the pitfx era. I've been using ifelse to run a series of tests to find the starting catcher. The code and errors are below -- also I intend to after getting this to work instead of printing "no" should it fail have similar ifelse tests nested in this until I work through from HmBat1Pos to HmBat9Pos...etc

```
atbat$starting_catcher_retro = ifelse(((atbat$date = retro_games$Date)                                       
                         & (atbat$pitcher_name = retro_games$HmStPchNm) 
                         & (atbat$num = 1) 
                         & (atbat$inning_side = "top")
                         & (retro_games$HmBat1Pos = 2)), 
                         retro_games$HmBat1ID, "no")
```

errors

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, date, value = c(13963, 13964, 13968,  : 
  replacement has 26726 rows, data has 2146373
```

I then tried to take out some of the code testing the date and still got errors. So I ran this instead

```
atbat$starting_catcher_retro = ifelse(((atbat$num = 1) 
                                         & (atbat$inning_side = "top")
                                         &(retro_games$HmBat1Pos = 2)), 
                                         retro_games$HmBat1ID, "no")
```

and got these other errors

```
Error in (atbat$num = 1) & (atbat$inning_side = "top") : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

---

response to comments

this was the code that I added and the error returned

```
> merged_df <- merge(atbat, retro_games,
+                    by.x = c("date", "pitcher_name"),
+                    by.y = c("Date", "HmStPchNm"), all.x = FALSE)
> 
> merged_df$starting_catcher_retro = with(merged_df, 
+                                         ifelse((num == 1) 
+                                                & (inning_side == "top")
+                                                & (HmBat3Pos == 2), 
+                                                HmBat3ID, "no"))
> 
> atbat$starting_catcher_retro <- merged_df$starting_catcher_retro[match(merged_df$unique_id, atbat$unique_id)]
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, starting_catcher_retro, value = c("no",  : 
  replacement has 566448 rows, data has 2146373
```

I also attempted a different approach to the one above which is based on the idea I had in my head -- below is that code and the errors returned where everything looks like it should work but there isn't even a new column created

```
atbat$starting_catcher_retro = ifelse(((retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) 
                                       & (retro_games$HmStPchNm %in% atbat$pitcher_name) 
                                       & (atbat$inning_side == "top")
                                       & (retro_games$HmBat1Pos == 2)), 
                                      retro_games$HmBat1ID, 
                                      ifelse(((retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) 
                                              & (retro_games$HmStPchNm %in% atbat$pitcher_name) 
                                              & (atbat$inning_side == "top")
                                              & (retro_games$HmBat2Pos == 2)), 
                                             retro_games$HmBat2ID, 
                                             ifelse(((retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) 
                                                     & (retro_games$HmStPchNm %in% atbat$pitcher_name) 
                                                     & (atbat$inning_side == "top")
                                                     & (retro_games$HmBat3Pos == 2)), 
                                                    retro_games$HmBat3ID, 
                                                    ifelse(((retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) 
                                                            & (retro_games$HmStPchNm %in% atbat$pitcher_name) 
                                                            & (atbat$inning_side == "top")
                                                            & (retro_games$HmBat4Pos == 2)), 
                                                           retro_games$HmBat4ID, 
                                                           ifelse(((retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) 
                                                                   & (retro_games$HmStPchNm %in% atbat$pitcher_name) 
                                                                   & (atbat$inning_side == "top")
                                                                   & (retro_games$HmBat5Pos == 2)), 
                                                                  retro_games$HmBat5ID, 
                                                                  ifelse(((retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) 
                                                                          & (retro_games$HmStPchNm %in% atbat$pitcher_name) 
                                                                          & (atbat$inning_side == "top")
                                                                          & (retro_games$HmBat6Pos == 2)), 
                                                                         retro_games$HmBat6ID, 
                                                                         ifelse(((retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) 
                                                                                 & (retro_games$HmStPchNm %in% atbat$pitcher_name) 
                                                                                 & (atbat$inning_side == "top")
                                                                                 & (retro_games$HmBat7Pos == 2)), 
                                                                                retro_games$HmBat7ID, 
                                                                                ifelse(((retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) 
                                                                                        & (retro_games$HmStPchNm %in% atbat$pitcher_name) 
                                                                                        & (atbat$inning_side == "top")
                                                                                        & (retro_games$HmBat8Pos == 2)), 
                                                                                       retro_games$HmBat8ID, 
                                                                                       ifelse(((retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) 
                                                                                               & (retro_games$HmStPchNm %in% atbat$pitcher_name) 
                                                                                               & (atbat$inning_side == "top")
                                                                                               & (retro_games$HmBat9Pos == 2)), 
                                                                                              retro_games$HmBat9ID, 
                                                                                              ifelse(((retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) 
                                                                                                      & (retro_games$VisStPchNm %in% atbat$pitcher_name) 
                                                                                                      & (atbat$inning_side == "bottom")
                                                                                                      & (retro_games$VisBat1Pos == 2)), 
                                                                                                     retro_games$VisBat1ID, 
                                                                                                     ifelse(((retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) 
                                                                                                             & (retro_games$VisStPchNm %in% atbat$pitcher_name) 
                                                                                                             & (atbat$inning_side == "bottom")
                                                                                                             & (retro_games$VisBat2Pos == 2)), 
                                                                                                            retro_games$VisBat12D, 
                                                                                                            ifelse(((retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) 
                                                                                                                    & (retro_games$VisStPchNm %in% atbat$pitcher_name) 
                                                                                                                    & (atbat$inning_side == "bottom")
                                                                                                                    & (retro_games$VisBat3Pos == 2)), 
                                                                                                                   retro_games$VisBat3ID, 
                                                                                                                   ifelse(((retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) 
                                                                                                                           & (retro_games$VisStPchNm %in% atbat$pitcher_name) 
                                                                                                                           & (atbat$inning_side == "bottom")
                                                                                                                           & (retro_games$VisBat4Pos == 2)), 
                                                                                                                          retro_games$VisBat4ID, 
                                                                                                                          ifelse(((retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) 
                                                                                                                                  & (retro_games$VisStPchNm %in% atbat$pitcher_name) 
                                                                                                                                  & (atbat$inning_side == "bottom")
                                                                                                                                  & (retro_games$VisBat5Pos == 2)), 
                                                                                                                                 retro_games$VisBat5ID, 
                                                                                                                                 ifelse(((retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) 
                                                                                                                                         & (retro_games$VisStPchNm %in% atbat$pitcher_name) 
                                                                                                                                         & (atbat$inning_side == "bottom")
                                                                                                                                         & (retro_games$VisBat6Pos == 2)), 
                                                                                                                                        retro_games$VisBat6ID, 
                                                                                                                                        ifelse(((retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) 
                                                                                                                                                & (retro_games$VisStPchNm %in% atbat$pitcher_name) 
                                                                                                                                                & (atbat$inning_side == "bottom")
                                                                                                                                                & (retro_games$VisBat7Pos == 2)), 
                                                                                                                                               retro_games$VisBat7ID, 
                                                                                                                                               ifelse(((retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) 
                                                                                                                                                       & (retro_games$VisStPchNm %in% atbat$pitcher_name) 
                                                                                                                                                       & (atbat$inning_side == "bottom")
                                                                                                                                                       & (retro_games$VisBat8Pos == 2)), 
                                                                                                                                                      retro_games$VisBat8ID, 
                                                                                                                                                      ifelse(((retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) 
                                                                                                                                                              & (retro_games$VisStPchNm %in% atbat$pitcher_name) 
& (atbat$inning_side == "bottom")
                                                                                                                                                              & (retro_games$VisBat9Pos == 2)), 
                                                                                                                                                             retro_games$VisBat9ID, ""))))))))))))))))))
```

and the error

```
Error in ans[test & ok] <- rep(yes, length.out = length(ans))[test & ok] : 
  replacement has length zero
In addition: There were 23 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In (retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) & (retro_games$HmStPchNm %in%  ... :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In (retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) & (retro_games$HmStPchNm %in%  ... :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3: In (retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) & (retro_games$HmStPchNm %in%  ... :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
4: In (retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) & (retro_games$HmStPchNm %in%  ... :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
5: In (retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) & (retro_games$HmStPchNm %in%  ... :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
6: In (retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) & (retro_games$HmStPchNm %in%  ... :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
7: In (retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) & (retro_games$HmStPchNm %in%  ... :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
8: In (retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) & (retro_games$HmStPchNm %in%  ... :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
9: In (retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) & (retro_games$HmStPchNm %in%  ... :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
10: In (retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) & (retro_games$HmStPchNm %in%  ... :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
11: In (retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) & (retro_games$HmStPchNm %in%  ... :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
12: In (retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) & (retro_games$HmStPchNm %in%  ... :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
13: In (retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) & (retro_games$HmStPchNm %in%  ... :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
14: In (retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) & (retro_games$HmStPchNm %in%  ... :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
15: In (retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) & (retro_games$HmStPchNm %in%  ... :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
16: In (retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) & (retro_games$HmStPchNm %in%  ... :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
17: In (retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) & (retro_games$HmStPchNm %in%  ... :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
18: In (retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) & (retro_games$HmStPchNm %in%  ... :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
19: In (retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) & (retro_games$VisStPchNm %in%  ... :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
20: In (retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) & (retro_games$VisStPchNm %in%  ... :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
21: In (retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) & (retro_games$VisStPchNm %in%  ... :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
22: In (retro_games$Date %in% atbat$date) & (retro_games$VisStPchNm %in%  ... :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
23: In rep(yes, length.out = length(ans)) :
  'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL
```

---

edit2

sample from both dataframes of first 15 rows was too long to include
here is a pastebin of that - https://pastebin.com/kTVEgdRs

Comment: Your logical test should use `==` instead of `=`, right? does that help?

Comment: @liuminzhao Rookie mistake by me you're right that helps...the only issue now is that the entire column is filled only with "no" even when I run it for the entire lineup...

Answer (score 1):

Usually `ifelse` is run within same data frame ensuring equal number of rows not across datasets. Consider merging first then run `ifelse`. Below runs a left join merge keeping all rows in *atbat*.

```
merged_df <- merge(atbat, retro_games,
                   by.x = c("date", "pitcher_name"),
                   by.y = c("Date", "HmStPchNm"), all.x = TRUE)

merged_df$starting_catcher_retro = with(merged_df, 
                                     ifelse((num == 1) 
                                             & (inning_side == "top")
                                             & (HmBat1Pos == 2), 
                                             HmBat1ID, "no")
                                     )
```

Comment: That looks a lot simplier than what I was trying but when using that I ran into 2 issues -- one is that when manually cross checking a few catchers by looking at the atbat then looking at the retrosheet I was getting the wrong ids where some were players who don't catch at all the second is an error off something I added to move that same data from the merged dataframe to the atbat dataframe - all above in my edited original post.

Comment: Looking at your `merge` attempt, you repeat same mistake of assigning `ifelse` across data frames. Don't do that. And `merge` can even cut down your very nested `ifelse`. Please `dput` a small sample of both data frames and your desired output.

Comment: Here is a pasetbin link to a dput of the first 15 rows of both - https://pastebin.com/kTVEgdRs - as for my desired output I just want a column in atbat with the catcher name only at what would be the first at bat because I can then have that catcher set for the entire game using a combination of the gamelink and which side of the inning (top or bottom). I have a seperate file from pitchfx which has defensive subsitutions I can can then use to update the name of the catcher for every game depending on the inning and if there was in fact a change once I know the starter.

Comment: Your link only has `dput` of *atbat*.

Comment: I also don't exact understand what you mean by me repeating the same mistake